# LWJGL font not rendering, even with depth test and texture_2D

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, slick, text

I'm running into an odd little problem here. I'm attempting to render a basic console over my LWJGL-based application, which should be easy enough through a decorator pattern of renderers (as in, one for the environment, and another chained to it for the text drawn on top of it). I thought that I could just use UnicodeFont (or even TrueTypeFont) for this, but I cannot seem to get it to render in the context of a 3D scene. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Here's the totality of the class (pardon the lack of cleanup):

```
static final Vector3f DRAW_COLOR = new Vector3f(1.0f, 0.2f, 0.2f);

    //CameraController is a class that manages the orientation of the camera, but not necessarily the player. For the moment, we're using FirstPersonCameraController;
    //later on, for the sake of sprite testing, it should probably be something like "ThirdPersonCameraController".
    static CameraController cameraController = new FirstPersonCameraController();

    static private UnicodeFont f = framework.util.UnicodeFontGenerator.generateUnicodeFont("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24);

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_DITHER);
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        // default draw color
        glColor3f(DRAW_COLOR.getX(), DRAW_COLOR.getY(), DRAW_COLOR.getZ());

    }

    @Override
    public void setup() {
    }

    @Override
    public void renderGraphics() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glPushMatrix();
        {
            movePlayer();
            drawShapes();
            drawText();
        }
        glPopMatrix();

    }

    public static CameraController getCameraController() {
        return FirstPersonRenderingLayer.cameraController;
    }

    /**
     * Apply any overhead operations and move the player through the applicable CameraController.
     */
    private void movePlayer() {
        cameraController.lookThrough();
    }

    private void drawText() {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        f.drawString(100, 200, "Text!!! TEXT!!!!!");
        GL11.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    private void drawShapes() {
        glColor3f(DRAW_COLOR.getX(), DRAW_COLOR.getY(), DRAW_COLOR.getZ());
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);
        GLUT.glutSolidCube(0.5f);

        glColor3f(0.2f, 1.0f, 0.2f);
        glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f);
        GLUT.glutSolidTeapot(0.5f);

        glColor3f(0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        glTranslatef(2.0f, 0.0f, -2.0f);
        GLUT.glutSolidTorus(0.15, 0.50, 24, 24);

        glColor3f(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.2f);
        glTranslatef(-4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GLUT.glutSolidSphere(0.50, 24, 24);

        glTranslatef(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    }

    @Override
    public void terminate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

My generateUnicodeFont() function is as follows:

```
public static UnicodeFont generateUnicodeFont(String fontName, int style, int size) {

        UnicodeFont ufont = new UnicodeFont(new java.awt.Font(fontName, style, size));
        ufont.addAsciiGlyphs();
        ColorEffect e = new ColorEffect();
        e.setColor(defaultColor);
        ufont.getEffects().add(e);
        try {
            ufont.loadGlyphs();
        } catch (SlickException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ufont;
    }
```

As of yet, I've gotten nothing but four solid-color perfectly rendered shapes. I'm not new to Java or programming, but I am new to LWJGL, Slick, and (relatively) OpenGL. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make this work with your code, but I'm afraid I would need everything to see what else you're doing to configure OpenGL.

I've had some problems of my own with displaying text onto my 3D scene, but I think I've isolated the problem.

Once I remove the following code from my initialisation, the text was displayed correctly:

```
GLU.gluPerspective(DEFAULT_FOV, ((float) width / (float) height), 0.3f, 1000.0f); //calculate perspective
```

I don't know what this code does besides calculating a field of view and changing perspectives, but my text gets displayed without this line, and disappears when I add it again. Someone with more knowledge on this subject should be able to explain why.

If you have that function in your code, try removing it and see if it fixes it. Then we can see how we can add field of view AND display text :-)

Comment: very helpful, thank you!

My best guess is that the text is somehow being clipped with my current technique; like it's too close to the player. I can't set the view bounds of gluPerspective to start at z = 0.0, or everything disappears (not sure why yet).

My thought is that I might be going about the whole thing wrong. My ideal is a transparent overlay of the console anyway. If I were to, say, create a tetragon over the field of view, and texture my text to that instead of the screen, it might help. Like a design pattern I learned from building audio-editing programs.

Comment: I have been reading **a lot** about it since I saw your question here (mainly on [The Coding Universe](http://www.thecodinguniverse.com) and Oscar's youtube tutorial about text) and it seems you should draw your GUI (text, menus) and 3D content totally separate. Before and after drawing text, you should switch to/from orthographic projection and when drawing 3D content switch to/from perspective projection. This way you can draw text on a 2D plane (ortho) and draw your 3D stuff in a 3D world (perspective)